# Problema con fgetc

Tags: c, archivo

Tengo un problema y es que fgetc no lee realmente lo que hay en el fichero.
Tengo el siguiente código:

```
int* readData(char* problem, int size) {
    FILE *f;
    //Obtenemos el fichero con el problema

    if ((f = fopen(problem, "r+")) == NULL){
        perror("Error, file doesn't exist");
        return NULL;
    }

    int n = size;

    int* problemArray = malloc ((n+1)*(n));
    int i;
    char data;

    //Libramos la primera posición
    fgetc(f);
    if (fgetc(f) - '0' != -38) {
        printf("Error, bad entry");
        return NULL;
    }

    //Obtenemos la representación en memoria del tablero
    for (i = 0; i < (n+1)*(n); i++){

        if ((data = fgetc(f)) == EOF){
            printf("Error, missing data\n");
            return NULL;
        }

        problemArray[i] = data - '0';
        printf("%c\n", data);


        if (problemArray[i] > (n-1) || problemArray[i] < 0){
            printf("Error, bad number %d + %d i\n", problemArray[i], i);
            //free(problemArray);
            return NULL;
        }

        printf("%d number\n", problemArray[i]);

        //Realizamos las correspondientes comprobaciones de formato
        data = fgetc(f);
        if((i % (n+1) == (n)) & (data - '0' != -38)){
            printf("Error, bad format1\n");
            //free(problemArray);
            return NULL;
        }

        if ((i % (n+1) != (n)) & ((data - '0' != -16) & (data - '0' != -48))){
            printf("Error, bad format2 + %d data + %d + i%ccadena\n", data-'0', i, data);
            //free(problemArray);
            return NULL;
        }

    }

    if (fgetc(f) != EOF){
        printf("Error, more numbers than predicted\n");
        //free(problemArray);
        return NULL;
    }

    return problemArray;
}
```

Lo que ocurre es que si le paso una entrada de tamaño mayor a 4x3, fgetc no me captura ningún número. Por ejemplo:

```
   0 1 0 2 3

   1 0 1 2 3

   2 3 0 1 2

   3 3 0 1 2
```

Nos daría la siguiente salida:

```
    0

    0 number

    1

    1 number

    0

    0 number

    2

    2 number

    3

    3 number

    1

    1 number

    0

    0 number

    1

    1 number

    2

    2 number

    3

    3 number

    2

    2 number

    3

    3 number

    0

    0 number

    1

    1 number

    2

    2 number

    3

    3 number

    3

    3 number

    0

    0 number

    Error, bad number -48 + 18 i
```

Mi problema es que lee el carácter -48, es decir, el caracter blanco en lugar de leer el número 1.
Alguien me podría ayudar?
Gracias

Comment: Y... ¿Cuál es el contenido del archivo?

Comment: El contenido del archivo son los números de la tabla mas 1 adicional en la parte de arriba para indicar el tamaño

Comment: para n=2 o n=3 funciona correctamente

Comment: `fgetc()` lee un solo carácter del fichero. Si el carácter es un espacio, eso será lo que retorne `fegetc()`. Una de dos, o eliminas los espacios del fichero (pero aún así tendrías problemas con los retornos de carro), o lees con otra función, como `fscanf()` que ignore los espacios.

Comment: El problema no son los espacios, si no un caracter ascii \000 que lee y no sé de donde sale. En cuanto a los espacios, me interesa que los lea

Comment: Gracias @JLDiaz, era el malloc lo que estaba mal, en cuanto al fichero, muestra los caracteres correctos

Comment: @JLDiaz Escribe la respuesta :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en un uso incorrecto de `malloc()` al cual hay que pasarle el *número de bytes* que necesitas, y no el número de *elementos*. En concreto, la línea

```
int* problemArray = malloc ((n+1)*(n));
```

debería ser

```
int* problemArray = malloc ((n+1)*(n)*sizeof(int));
```

Al no reservar suficiente espacio, a partir de un cierto número de caracteres leidos estabas empezando a escribir fuera de la zona reservada, con resultados imprevisibles.